# Problem with using APM in asp.net core application

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, elastic-stack

I'm using **asp.net core and docker** and the goal is to use **Elastic APM**, here is my configuration:

**Program.cs:**

```
app.UseAllElasticApm(builder.Configuration);
```

**appsettings.json:**

```
"ElasticApm": {
    "ServiceName": "Appraisal360APMSerivce",
    "LogLevel": "verbose",
    "ServerUrl": "http://localhost:8200",
    "apm-server-secret-token": "",
    "TransactionSampleRate": 1.0
  }
```

**docker-compose file:**

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  apm-server:
    image: docker.elastic.co/apm/apm-server:7.15.2
    ports:
      - 8200:8200
      - 6060:6060
    volumes:
      - ./apm-server.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/apm-server.yml
    environment:
      - output.elasticsearch.hosts=["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
    networks:
      - elastic
    command: >
      apm-server -e
        -E apm-server.rum.enabled=true
        -E apm-server.host=0.0.0.0:8200
        -E setup.kibana.host=kibana:5601
    cap_drop:
      - ALL
    cap_add:
      - CHOWN
      - DAC_OVERRIDE
      - SETGID
      - SETUID
    logging:
      driver: 'json-file'
      options:
          max-size: '200m'
          max-file: '50'

  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    image: elasticsearch:8.5.0
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
  networks:
      - elastic

  kibana:
    container_name: kibana
    image: kibana:8.5.0
    volumes:
      - ./kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
    environment:
      - XPACK_MONITORING_ENABLED=true
      - XPACK_MONITORING_COLLECTION_ENABLED=true
      - XPACK_SECURITY_ENABLED=true
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200
 ports:
      - 5601:5601
    networks:
      - elastic

  elastic-agent:
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/elastic-agent:8.5.0
    container_name: elastic-agent
    restart: always
    user: root # note, synthetic browser monitors require this set to `elastic-agent`
    environment:
     - fleet-server-es=http://localhost:9200
     - fleet-server-service-token=*****
     - fleet-server-policy=fleet-server-policy

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch-data:
```

my **container** is up and running without error

[image]

now the problem is here that **fleet server** does not find any **connection** like what u see in the picture:

[image]

**i would be thankful if there is any help**

Comment: Are you sure pointing it to a localhost URL will work?

Comment: @Sanketh B. K tell me exactly what across in your mind sir

Comment: I am not familiar with Fleet, but in general way localhost URL's can only be accessed from your computer, so Fleet server won't be able to use it